# plugin in gazebo

Tags: control, ros, gazebo, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am trying to make a plugin in gazebo to control a 1 joint urdf model.
I am able to give it tourque by this command  -

```
 this->only_joint_->SetForce(0,(-10*(this->only_joint_->GetAngle(0)));
```

but if i try giving a different command like-

```
this->only_joint_->SetForce(0,(-3*this->only_joint_->GetVelocity(0)+10*(this->only_joint_->GetAngle(0)));
```

it isn't willing to compile.
any idea?

Thanks
Nachum

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46145/plugin-in-gazebo/) by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2012-10-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-10-17**:
For questions like this, it is very helpful if you add the actual error message you encounter. (You can edit your post to do that)

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-10-18**:
GetAngle(0) returns a gazebo::math::Angle object, you need to invoke the GetAngle().GetAsRadian() member function as you did in your own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

O.k
I just put it in 2 different lines and it works nicely.

```
this->only_joint_->SetForce(0,-2*this->only_joint_->GetAngle(0).GetAsRadian());
 this->only_joint_->SetForce(0,-2*this->only_joint_->GetVelocity(0));
```

---

Originally posted by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) with karma: 208 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2012-10-18**:
for what do i need the zero in GetAngle(0)?

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-10-18**:
for some joints such as Hinge2Joint and Universal joints, there are two states per joint.

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2012-10-20**:
what are the two states?